# Dynamic calculation of discounts for each day in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a range dates for rental products. For this, I use Jquery UI Datepicker.

This allows me to choose two dates and count the number of days in the range of these dates.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker');

function enabling_date_picker() {

    // Only on front-end and product page
    if (is_product() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()):

    // Load the Datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');

    endif;
}


// The jQuery script
add_action('wp_footer', 'rental_date_jquery_script');

function rental_date_jquery_script() {
    // Only on front-end and product page
    if (is_product() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()):

            ?>
            <script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var from = new Date();
    var to = new Date();
    var dayDiff = 1;
     var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: 14,
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                                    selectedDate, instance.settings);
                    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);

                    if (this.id == "from") {
                            from = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                            if (!(to == "")) {
                                    update_days()
                            }
                    }
                    if (this.id == "to") {
                            to = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                            update_days()
                    }
            }
    });
    function update_days() {
            dayDiff = Math.ceil((to - from) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            $("#days").empty()
            $("#days").append(dayDiff)
    } 
}); 
    </script> 

    <?php

    endif;
}

// Add a custom field before single add to cart
add_action('woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'display_rental_date_custom_fields', 5);

function display_rental_date_custom_fields() {

    echo '<div>
        <h3>From:</h3>
        <input id="from" type="text" name="from" readonly />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>To:</h3>
        <input id="to" type="text" name="to" readonly />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>You have chosen: </span>
        <span id="days">< /span> days.
    </div>';
}
```

---

**Update:**

I would like to make a dynamic discount calculation. I will explain what I mean:

1. Regular price for products is the rental price per day.
2. The maximum rental period is unlimited.
3. Percentage discount on the first day - 100%
4. Discount, starting from the second day of rent - 50%.

For example, if a customer rents a product worth $100 per day for a period of 5 days, the following is obtained:

```
Day 1 - $100 (100%)
Day 2 - $50 (50%)
Day 3 - $50 (50%)
Day 4 - $50 (50%)
Day 5 - $50 (50%)
```

In the end, it should work out - $300 for 5 days.

At the same time, it is necessary to calculate the total rental price and show the new price on the page of a single product. All products are variable.

How to make such a functional? Need your help!

I hope that many developers will need this functionality in the future.

Comment: "rental products" - how exactly did you make them as rental products? Using a plugin (other than WooCommerce itself)?

Comment: @Sally CJ Buy of products will not be. Only rent. Therefore, it was decided to make the basic price as the price for the rental of the product. No rental or discount plugins are used.

Comment: "*dynamic* discount calculation" - you're *not* referring to a JavaScript-based tool, are you? Do you need just the function (in PHP) which does the calculation? Do you already have the code which saves the rental dates/period fields?

Comment: @Sally CJ Yes, I need functional based on PHP. Unfortunately, the code that I have, I showed above. There is nothing else ((

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate this: "*show the new price on the page of a single product*"?

Comment: Sorry, this does not need to be done on the product page. The total rental price, for example, $200 for 5 days, must be in the cart and on the checkout page.

Comment: I've just posted a working solution. Let me know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changes to your existing code

In the `display_rental_date_custom_fields()` code:

1. I changed the field `name` and `id` so that they start with `rental_period_` because `to` and `from` are too generic..
2. I added a hidden `input` field named `is_rental` which indicates the product that's being purchased is available *for rent*.
3. I added the `value` attribute to the date fields.

```php
function display_rental_date_custom_fields() {
    ?>
        <div>
            <h3>From:</h3>
            <input id="rental_period_from" type="text" name="rental_period_from" readonly value="<?php echo esc_attr( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'rental_period_from' ) ); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>To:</h3>
            <input id="rental_period_to" type="text" name="rental_period_to" readonly value="<?php echo esc_attr( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'rental_period_to' ) ); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>You have chosen: </span>
            <span id="days">0</span> days.
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="is_rental" value="1">
    <?php
}
```

And you should use the revised date picker script [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWGvMP?editors=1010) — just visit the page to see the changes.

---

### New code to be added to your existing code

*(Copy the snippets below and paste them below the `display_rental_date_custom_fields` code.)*

SNIPPET 1: **The PHP function for making the calculation:**

*See it in SNIPPET #3 below.*

SNIPPET 2: **Processes the *submitted* rental period (i.e. start and end dates):**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'my_add_rental_period_data' );
function my_add_rental_period_data( $cart_item_data ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['is_rental'] ) ) {
        // Throwing an Exception will prevent the product from being added to the cart.

        // Validate POSTed values.
        if ( empty( $_POST['rental_period_from'] ) ||
            empty( $_POST['rental_period_to'] ) ) {
            throw new Exception( 'Rental start and end dates must both be specified.' );
        }

        $now = date_create( 'now' );
        $from = date_create( $_POST['rental_period_from'] );
        $to = date_create( $_POST['rental_period_to'] );
        // Validate rental dates.
        if ( ! $from || ! $to || $to < $from ) {
            throw new Exception( 'Invalid rental dates.' );
        }

        $format = 'd.m.Y'; // dd.mm.yyyy
        $rental_days = date_diff( $from, $to )->days;
        $cart_item_data['rental_period'] = [
            'from'    => $from->format( $format ),
            'to'      => $to->format( $format ),
            'days'    => $rental_days,
        ];
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

SNIPPET 3: **Applies the discount to the rental products in the cart:**

```php
function my_set_rental_product_price( array $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['rental_period'] ) ) {
        $rental_days = $cart_item['rental_period']['days'];
        if ( $rental_days > 1 ) {
            $regular_price = $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price();
            $price = $regular_price / 2 * ( $rental_days - 1 ) + $regular_price;
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
        }
        // else, no discount given.

        return $cart_item['data'];
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'my_apply_discount_to_rental_products' );
function my_apply_discount_to_rental_products() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        my_set_rental_product_price( $cart_item );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', 'my_apply_discount_to_rental_product', 10, 2 );
function my_apply_discount_to_rental_product( $product, $cart_item ) {
    if ( $rental_product = my_set_rental_product_price( $cart_item ) ) {
        return $rental_product;
    }
    return $product;
}
```

SNIPPET 4: **Displays the rental period in the main table on the cart page:**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'my_add_rental_period_meta', 10, 2 );
function my_add_rental_period_meta( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['rental_period'] ) ) {
        $period =& $cart_item['rental_period'];

        $days = $period['days'] . ' ' . _n( 'day', 'days', $period['days'] );
        $range = ( $period['from'] === $period['to'] ) ? $period['from'] . ' (today)' :
            $days . ' (' . $period['from'] . ' - ' . $period['to'] . ')';

        $item_data[] = [
            'key'   => 'Rental Period',
            'value' => $range,
        ];
    }
    return $item_data;
}
```

SNIPPET 5: **Adds the rental period as metadata of the product in the order:** (this is needed specifically for back-end/admin or later access)

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'my_add_rental_period_meta2', 10, 3 );
function my_add_rental_period_meta2( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['rental_period'] ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( '_rental_period', $cart_item['rental_period'] );
    }
    return $item;
}
```

SNIPPET 6: **Allows the saved metadata above be displayed, for example, in the "Order Details" table and the "New Order" admin email:**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'my_add_rental_period_meta3', 10, 2 );
function my_add_rental_period_meta3( $formatted_meta, $item ) {
    if ( $period = $item->get_meta( '_rental_period', true ) ) {
        $days = $period['days'] . ' ' . _n( 'day', 'days', $period['days'] );
        $range = ( $period['from'] === $period['to'] ) ? $period['from'] . ' (today)' :
            $days . ' (' . $period['from'] . ' - ' . $period['to'] . ')';

        $formatted_meta[] = (object) [
            'key'           => 'rental_period',
            'value'         => $period,
            'display_key'   => 'Rental Period',
            'display_value' => $range,
        ];
    }
    return $formatted_meta;
}
```

### Screenshots

1. [Single product page, after adding a (variable) product to the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNfZb.png)

[image]

Comment: I probably explained badly what was needed. See ... For example, the cost of rentals a product is $500 per day. The client chose the rental period - 21 days. We get $500 for the first day and $250 for 20 days. The result is an amount of $5,500. In your code for some reason, it turns out the amount of $5000.

Comment: Yes, because I thought the discount for the first day is 100% - which means free... lol. But I've updated the answer/calculation - see SNIPPET 1 and SNIPPET 3 parts. And the rest are doing good, right?

Comment: Yes, everything seems to be working correctly. I will test some more time. Thank you so much for the answer and help!

Comment: You're welcome. :) And you should know that I've edited SNIPPET 3 (before you accepted the answer). Have a nice day!

Comment: Also, just remove the `$now = date_create( 'now' );` in *SNIPPET 2*. It's not being used there, but I forgot to remove it..

Comment: Ok. I'll do it. Thanks!